# React: Update field values dynamically from separate input states

Tags: reactjs, forms, dom, react-state

I'm attempting to create a react app that focuses on automatically doing calculations and alterations to a D&D characters based on stats and attributes that is inputed.

An example; A character is size "Medium", when it is selected from the select field, the fields "space", "reachTall", reachLength" will automatically be altered to the specific values.

The issue I'm running into is I'm unable to find the correct way of accessing the states of those select inputs. The logic is to call the handleUpdate(size) method and access the states that need to be updated with the corresponding values, but I haven't found a way to access their states to change their values without direct user input.

```
class SizeSpace extends React.Component<any,any>
{
  constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      //POPULATE FROM XML PLAYER FILE
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

handleChange (evt) {
    // check it out: we get the evt.target.name (which will be either "email" or "password")
    // and use it to target the key on our `state` object with the same name, using bracket syntax

    console.log(evt);
    console.log(evt.target);
    console.log(evt.target.name);

    this.setState({ [evt.target.name]: evt.target.value });


  }

handleUpdate(size)
  {
    switch (size) {
      case value: "Fine"
        //Update space
        //Update reachTall
        //Update reachLength
        break;

      default:
        break;
    }
  }



render() {
    return (
      <form>

        <label>
          Size:
        </label>
        <select value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange}>
          <option value="Fine">Fine</option>
          <option value="Diminutive">Diminutive</option>
          <option value="Tiny">Tiny</option>
          <option value="Small">Small</option>
          <option value="Medium">Medium</option>
          <option value="Large">Large</option>
          <option value="Huge">Huge</option>
          <option value="Gargantuan">Gargantuan</option>
          <option value="Colossal">Colossal</option>
        </select>

        <label>
          Space:
        </label>
        <select name="space" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange}>
          <option value=".5">.5ft</option>
          <option value="1">1ft</option>
          <option value="2.5">2.5ft</option>
          <option value="5">5ft</option>
          <option value="10">10ft</option>
          <option value="15">15ft</option>
          <option value="20">20ft</option>
          <option value="30">30ft</option>
        </select>

        <label>
          Reach: Tall
        </label>
        <select name="reachTall" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange}>
          <option value="0">0ft</option>
          <option value="5">5ft</option>
          <option value="10">10ft</option>
          <option value="15">15ft</option>
          <option value="20">20ft</option>
          <option value="30">30ft</option>
        </select>

        <label>
          Length:
        </label>
        <select name="reachLength" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange}>
          <option value="0">0ft</option>
          <option value="5">5ft</option>
          <option value="10">10ft</option>
          <option value="15">15ft</option>
          <option value="20">20ft</option>
        </select>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

export default SizeSpace;
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that - in your first select, the `name` attribute is missing.

In general, when you provide `value` to your `select`, you will need to provide the key which you set dynamically in your handleChange. In your case it is `name`.

**Like this:**

```js
<select name="space" value={this.state.space} onChange={this.handleChange}>
          <option value=".5">.5ft</option>
          <option value="1">1ft</option>
          <option value="2.5">2.5ft</option>
          <option value="5">5ft</option>
          <option value="10">10ft</option>
          <option value="15">15ft</option>
          <option value="20">20ft</option>
          <option value="30">30ft</option>
        </select>
```